Changes are not reflected on formula with related child record field within flow when invocable method finish
I have a flow with multiple invocable methods.

First method updates parent record - lookup field to another record is changed to newly created one.
Second method send mail with link to that record (Formula Field) and always I getting wrong link which points to previously associated child record.

I wonder if I need to re-query parent record in flow and that way changes will be reflected on formula field?

I suspect you have answered your own question. Without re-querying the record, the formula field won't be re-evaluated and hence the issue you're facing.

Although not always a strict rule, a good idea is to pass only IDs to invocables that then requery the object before performing work.

I am passing Id of the record and set whatId  like following ->              mail.setWhatId(request.recordId. Merge fields are fetched in template so what I need to re-query here?
